# How to prove the following by epsilon delta definition?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove that $$\underset{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\lim} (x^2+y^2) \log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) = 0$$ by $\epsilon- \delta$ definition. I can easily prove it by L-Hospital rule, but unable to do with definition.

Comment: Needless to use L'Hospital's rule for this: after a change of variables, it a standard high-school limit!

Comment: That will be $(r^2/2)(\log r)$

Comment: The substitution in question would be $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ which means that it becomes $r^2 \log r$. Not that it alters the result, but nevertheless...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint for the ε-δ method:**

First change  variables, setting $s=\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. You obtain the expression $-\dfrac{\ln s}{s^2}$, in which $s\to +\infty$.

Note (or prove if this is not known to you) that for $s>1$, one has$$\ln s<2\sqrt s$$
so you can apply the ε-δ method to $\;\dfrac2{s^{3/2}}$.

Comment: Note to the proposer: $\lim_{s\to \infty}(\ln s)/s=0$ implies that $\lim_{s\to \infty}(\ln s)^a/s^b=0$ for all positive $ a,b$ because $(\ln s)^a/s^b=$ $((\ln s)/s^{b/a})^a=$ $((a/b)(\ln t)/t)^a$ where $ t=s^{b/a}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Of course, if one knows this result (it should be known from high school, in my opinion), the proof is still shorter.

Comment: @Bernard Your inequality is not correct as if $s \to \infty$, left side going to $\infty$ but right side is going to $0$.

Comment: @MittalG: You're right. I was thinking of the way to prove it (via derivatives) and I messed up with the inequality between derivatives. Thanks for pointing it! 'Tis fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta >0$ such that $\forall (x,y):\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta \Rightarrow |(x^2+y^2) \log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|< \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon>0$.

For $\delta \leq 1$

$$|(x^2+y^2) \log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}| \leq \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}+ \frac{(\log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})^2}{2} $$

Now $$\frac{(\log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})^2}{2}< \epsilon \Rightarrow \log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\sqrt{2 \epsilon} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+y^2} <e^{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}$$

Take $\delta \leq\min\{1,2\sqrt[4]{\epsilon},e^{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}}\}$